# How to use android.os.Process in junit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to implement a simple test that uses android.os.Process.myPid (actually I have a large class that uses myPid, but to avoid posting large source I simplified everything down to this):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class ProcessTest {
    @Test
    public void testTest() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPid() {
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        //assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

First test passes ok, but second fails with this error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Process.myPid()I
```

What's wrong? How to test classes that use android.os.Process?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in unit tests. You can't access Android OS packages in unit tests. You can mock them!  You want a process id, but there's no OS running (apart from the machine you're developing on).

Answer (score 0):

After a while I found solution for my problem -- **instrumentation tests**. Well, yes, as Krzysztof Kubicki pointed out, it can't be done in unit tests. But while it's possible to mock things, is difficult in real case. I was able to mock pid for my simple test, but the real thing was AesCbcWithIntegrity by Tozny with all bells and whistles, including things like this:

```
int bytesRead = (Integer) Class
    .forName("org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto")
     .getMethod("RAND_load_file", String.class, long.class)
     .invoke(null, "/dev/urandom", 1024);
```

This is kinda difficult to mock. So, instead of mocking I created instrumentation test and ran tests on emulator.

And that solved my problem without much effort. Yes, instrumentation tests are slow compared to regular unit testing, but at least it works.